# Open Excel with password in C#, and close the excel externally

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am looking for a way to open the password protected Excel file in Excel from my c# program.

Please notice I just need to open it for my user.  I am not looking for something like Excel Interop to modify the file.

For a file that has no password, I can simply launch the process start with the full path file name as a parameter.  But this one has password in it, so it can't be done like this.

If I use Excel interope to open it, I can open it, but the Excel process will leave there when user close the Excel window.

```
var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.Visible = true;
var wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"d:\temp\test.xlsx", Password:"1234");
```

Since user will be modifying the file in the Excel window and then close the windows.  This part is out of my control.  I simply just want to launch the file, then I don't have to care about it.  But by using Excel interope, the COM is actually referecing back to my c# program, so that the whole Excel process can't be disposed completely.

Comment: Does the user know the password, and if so are you satisfied with opening the document and having them type it in? Or is the password meant to be a secret from the user?

Comment: The user doesn't know the password.  These files can only be opened from my application.

Comment: Using Excel Interop the Excel process will be terminated when your application is terminated

Answer (score 1):

I think I know a workaround for it.

Create a helper C# console application called `OpenExcelWorkbookWithPassword.exe` which looks like that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var excelapp = new Excel.Application();
    excelapp.Visible = true;
    Excel.Workbook workbook = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(args[0], Password: args[1]);
}
```

and use this from your main application with the following code:

```
string path = @"d:\temp\test.xlsx";
string pw = "1234";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("OpenExcelWorkbookWithPassword.exe", path + " " + pw);
```

When the user is closing Excel the `Excel.exe` process will be terminated even if your main application is still running.

Comment: Thanks Wollmich.  It seems working great!  Do you know why does it work?

Comment: I think the `Excel.exe` COM server process is running at least as long as the host process is running. If `excelapp.Visible = true` then the `Excel.exe` process can run even when the host process has terminated.

> Why does it work?
The main application starts `OpenExcelWorkbookWithPassword.exe` in a different process and doesn't wait for it. `OpenExcelWorkbookWithPassword.exe` starts Excel and then terminates itself. So when the user closes Excel the `Excel.exe` process gets terminated because the host process `OpenExcelWorkbookWithPassword.exe` is already terminated.

Hope this helps